# Converting VARCHAR to floating decimal in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, ansi-sql

I’m trying to convert a “string” column into all float values and can’t seem to get the correct output. The STRING values are all in #.## format (eg. 2.33, 4.25, 3.75, etc.) I have a query that looks to add a new column based on two conditions, one of which conditions requires the conversion:

```
SELECT 
    time, score, 
    CASE 
        WHEN time >= 3 AND CAST(score AS DECIMAL) >= 3 
            THEN ‘Yes’ 
            ELSE ‘No’ 
    END AS Recommendation
FROM
    table1
```

My output, however, isn’t capturing the correct result:

| Time | Score | Recommendation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1.2 | Yes |
| 5 | 2.1 | Yes |
| 2 | 4.1 | No |

In this case, I would expect the first two rows to be “No”, since the score that we converted to a float is less than 3.00.

Comment: which databse system are you using?

Comment: 1) Output `cast(score as decimal)` in your select as well to verify it's what you think it is. 2) It's possible there's a precedence issue. Try `WHEN time >= 3 AND (CAST(score AS DECIMAL) >= 3)` 3) Your query has the wrong quotes around Yes and No and Recommendation. Are you sure this is the real query?

Comment: Loading numbers in text form is just asking for all kinds of trouble. I would load them as numbers in the first place and forget about all this headache.

Comment: `decimal` without a precision defaults to 0 so it's rounding it.

Comment: converting strings into numbers can fail e.g. "abcdefg" cannot be converted to a number. That's why the very first comment asks "which database are you using?" **because syntax differs** e.g. in MS SQL Server you can use `try_cast` but this does not exist in other databases. Choose a tag that tells us which database is in use (& don't use the tag "sql")

Comment: @Charlieface ...except Postgres who find that to be a silly default; it means no limit. Still, doesn't explain why it's failing.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://dbfiddle.uk/2VXDDkyX or with cast in select as suggested: https://dbfiddle.uk/gaM_oktj  Also WHY Floating point?  Don't you want scale & Precision?  If you're dealing with extremely small or large numbers floating point makes sense.  if you're dealing with precision; don't use floating point; but then you say decimal in question details... so are you after floating point as subject suggests or decimal as question body suggests...

Comment: @xQbert The question says floating point, but their implementation is using an arbitrary precision `decimal` (tho incorrectly).

Comment: `decimal` is an [arbitrary precision number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). `float` is a [floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). They're different things. You had it right the first time. The problem is you're missing the scale and precision arguments, it should be like `CAST(score AS DECIMAL(9,1))`

Comment: What we need to see is the output of `cast(score as decimal)`. `select time, score, cast(score as decimal), case when ... from table1`.

Comment: @Schwern: and it would not hurt to add: `cast(score as decimal(9,2))`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT time, score, 
       CASE 
          WHEN time >= 3 
               AND CAST(REPLACE(score, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(16,2)) >= 3.0 
             THEN 'Yes' 
          ELSE 'No' 
       END AS Recommendation
FROM   table1
```

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation. It looks like you're trying to account for the possibility that the numbers are in `1,2` format. But the given example shows `1.2`.